# How do I get this Mathematical Symbol in Latex?

Tags: symbols, relation-symbols

I am doing a project report and there is a certain kind of relation that I want to express between two quantities A and B. The relation is something like **"A is neither greater than or less than B"** (These two quantities are not numbers, they are kind of valuation profiles that I need in my project). Anyways, I wanted to create a symbol to denote this relationship. Something like the image attached. Can anyone please help in creating it. (Or let me know if such a symbol already exists). Thank You.[image].

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Search for "The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List". It contain all known symbols. Maybe it already exist.

Comment: It could make sense.  For instance, a matrix could be neither positive definite nor negative definite, and you might want a symbol for that property.  Indeed, it's close to the concept of indefinite matrix.

Comment: As a tangential remark: in order theory there are established notions of [incomparability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparability). Wikipedia gives one set of notations that is somewhat frequently in use.

Comment: unicode character is `U+2279`

Answer (score 8):

Something like this?

[image: not-greater-or-less-than]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
 \not\gtrless
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks like the relation is ‘neither more, neither less, nor equal’ ;o) Lichtenberg's symbol?