# How to create "not less than or greater than" symbol?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, math-operators, relation-symbols

I recently came across this meme:

[image: equal? no, not less or greater]

(Source: [@nathanaelnoir](https://twitter.com/nathanaelnoir/status/1359903129320488967) on Twitter)

How can you create that second symbol in LaTeX?

Apparently, several packages do include `\nlessgtr`, but they have a diagonal slash rather than a vertical strikethrough. (`\not\lessgtr` produces the same thing.) How can you create a vertical strikethrough through a lessgtr sign?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get this Mathematical Symbol in Latex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319852/how-do-i-get-this-mathematical-symbol-in-latex)

Comment: Related: [How to negate a specific symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140996/5764)

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450705/what-is-the-not-less-than-operator-in-latex/450709 also

Comment: @naphaneal I talked about `\not\lessgtr` in the question, and explained why what I wanted was different

Comment: @Werner Same response^

Comment: @Rmano Detexify didn't help

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger: How about [Vertical line superimposed over a letter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/179602/5764).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED to apply `\mathrel` to get proper spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\nlg{\mathrel{\ensurestackMath{\stackengine{0pt}{%
  \stackanchor[-.5ex]{<}{>}}{\mid}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}}}
\begin{document}
$x \nlg y$
\end{document}
```

[image]